# Android Navigation Architecture not navigating when phone screen is OFF

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have the following architecture in my project:

`MainActivity` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`nav_graph` design:

[image]

`nav_graph` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.example.LoginFragment"
        android:label="LoginFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/loginToContentAction"
            app:destination="@id/contentFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
        android:name="com.example.ContentFragment"
        android:label="ContentFragment" />
</navigation>
```

In the `LoginFragment`, I have the following logic:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if(presenter.isUserLogged()) {
        // getNav() returns NavController from the MainActivity
        getNav().navigateTo(R.id.loginToContentAction)
        return
    }

    // init login views etc
}
```

It works perfectly if the phone screen is turned ON, but (for example) if I deploy build via Android Studio, and phone screen is OFF, it will not navigate to `ContentFragment` and stay in the `LoginFragment`. I debugged the situation, and code enters `NavController.navigate(R.id.loginToContentAction)` and steps into it, but it doesn't actually navigate. Any ideas what might be a cause of this?

Comment: Activities are usually paused when the screen turns off, or get paused if the screen is turned off. It might be pausing at a weird point, which messes up the flow.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Same problem here. I have tried adquiring a partial wake lock, but it did not work. In My case is a navigation that happens when a quick process ends in bkg, but if the user press the power button during it, the navigation is called but does not happens.

Comment: is there an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am exactly in the same situation. I didn't find a clean solution yet, and the only workaround for me it's to skip the navigation if screen is off. Then in "onStart", I perform the previously skipped navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, I have solved this problem.

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
    findNavController().navigate( R.id.YOUR_ACTION_ID)
}
```

**Furthermore, this extension function can be used to do any task with delay when fragment is in started state.**

This extension function can be used to navigate when the screen is turned on or normally after a delay.

```
fun Fragment.doWithDelay(delay: Long, performTask: () -> Unit) {
    Timer().schedule(timerTask {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                if (!this@doWithDelay.isDetached && this@doWithDelay.isAdded)
                    this@doWithDelay.activity?.runOnUiThread { performTask.invoke() }
            }
        }
    }, delay)
}
```

**How to use :**

```
 doWithDelay(YOUR_REQUIRED_DELAY) {
       findNavController().navigate(R.id.YOUR_NAVIGATION_ACTION_ID)
 }
```

It's working fine for me. If I'm wrong, kindly make me correct.